# Phonegap bluetooth plugin not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, bluetooth

First time poster here , so I'm sorry if this question is asked incorrect or if there are any issues.

I'm working on a phonegap app for which I need to be able to set up a bluetooth connection between a tablet (android in this case) and a Win CE PC.
Currently i'm trying to get the bluetooth part to work on the tablet and i'm using the plug in you can find at https://github.com/tanelih/phonegap-bluetooth-plugin 
And for the momemt I'm just trying to enable and disable the Bluetooth on the device.

In my bluetoothpage.js file i'm using the following method

window.bluetooth.prototype.enable(bluetoothTestSucces(),bluetoothTestFail());

The bluetoothTestSucces and bluetoothTestFail functions just show an alert, nothing else.
And if i understand the working of phonegap plugins correctly this uses the following code in my bluetooth.js file

Bluetooth.prototype.enable = function(onSuccess, onError)

```
{
    exec(onSuccess, onError, "Bluetooth", "enable", []);
}
```

which calls

private void enable(JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackCtx)

```
{       
    try
    {
        _bluetooth.enable();
        callbackCtx.success();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        this.error(callbackCtx, e.getMessage(), BluetoothError.ERR_UNKNOWN);
    }
}
```

in my BluetoothPlugin.java file.

And if the java file returns Succes bluetoothTestSucces() is used and if the java file returns an error bluetoothTestFail() is used.

But for some reason it runs both and does not turn on bluetooth on my device.
I'm almost certain I've forgotten a link to a file or have linked it wrong somewhere.
But I've followed the instructions that were included in the plugin.

I've included the Bluetooth permission in my AndoridManifest file which is located in the root directory of my app

I've included the plugin in my config.xml file which is located in res/xml

I've required the plugin after the deviceready event as follows

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady()
{

```
window.bluetooth = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/bluetooth");
```

}

Could anyone tell me how to fix this or what i've done wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

after finaly being able to use eclipse to do some debugging
I got the following error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'enable' of undefined.

**UPDATE 2**

I think I called the method wrong, it should have been window.bluetooth.enable instead of window.bluetooth.prototype.enable. 
Now I get the following error;

"Bluetooth binder is null" with the tag "BluetoothAdapter"

Also when I run it on the emulator it displays only the bluetoothTestFail() function (which is how it should be) but when I run it on the device nothing happens, no function is called nor is Bluetooth turned on/off

**Update 3**

I've ran my project via eclipse as an app on my device and now it works fine, no problems.
But when I convert it to an app using phonegap it doesn't work anymore.

thanks

Martijn

PS: I'm sorry for any language errors, English isn't my native language.

edit: forgot to include some code

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be calling the method via `prototype`. If you take a look at the included `bluetooth.js` file, you'll find the lines containing:

```
var bluetooth = new Bluetooth();
module.exports = bluetooth;
```

This basically means that the plugin 'exports' an instance of `Bluetooth` from which you can call the methods from directly.

In your post, you say you're also passing the callbacks as such:

```
window.bluetooth.prototype.enable(bluetoothTestSucces(),bluetoothTestFail());
```

This means that both the `bluetoothTestSucces` and `bluetoothTestFail` functions are being called and their return values are being passed in instead.

Try calling the method like this and see if it works.

```
window.bluetooth.enable(bluetoothTestSucces, bluetoothTestFail);
```

Hopefully this helps!

**EDIT**

Glad to hear you got it working at least somehow.

I'm not sure what you mean by converting it to an app using PhoneGap? I've only ever ran the Android project via eclipse myself, so I'm not sure what's causing problems.

You could try adding some basic debugging with `console.log` to the `bluetooth.js` file to see if the plugin methods are being called at all. You can also do the same for the Java-files to see if that helps you track down the culprit.

Hope you get it working.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I came to the same conclussion after playing with some test functions. Now I get an error saying "Bluetooth binder is null" and when I run it on the device nothing happens but on the emulator I get the bluetoothTestFail message.